# Extract value from key value pair using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a file having key-value data in it. I have to get the value of a specific key in that file. I have the Linux equivalent command:

File:

```
    key1=val1
    key2=val2
    ..
```

Command:

```
cat path/file | grep 'key1' | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'
```

Output:

```
val1
```

I want to achieve the same output on windows as well. I don't have any experience working in power shell but I tried with the following:

```
Get-Content "path/file" | Select-String -Pattern 'key1' -AllMatches
```

But I'm getting output like this:

```
key1=val1
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You've left out the `awk` step entirely, which splits the string on `=` and selects the second part. The PowerShell equivalent is `('key=value' -split '=')[1]`, which you'll need to use in a ``| Foreach-Object { ... }``. (This is almost but not entirely spelling out the answer.)

Comment: it was enough to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

```
<# required powershell version 5.1 or later
@'
key1=val1
key2=val2
'@ | out-file d:\temp.txt
#>

(Get-Content d:\temp.txt | ConvertFrom-StringData).key1
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:

- With your *specific input format* (`key=value` lines), [Алексей Семенов's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65096973/45375) offers the simplest solution, using [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata); note that it ignores whitespace around `=` and trailing whitespace after the value.
- The answer below focuses *generally* on **how to implement `grep` and `awk`-like functionality in PowerShell**.

---

It is not the direct equivalent of your approach, but a faster and PowerShell-idiomatic solution using a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement:

```
# Create a sample file
@'
key1=val1
key2=val2
'@ > sample.txt

# -> 'val1'
switch -Regex -File ./sample.txt { '^\s*key1=(.*)' { $Matches[1]; break } }
```

- The `-Regex` option implicitly performs a [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) operation on each line of the input file (thanks to `-File`), and the results are available in the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches).
- `$Matches[1]` therefore returns what the first (and only) capture group (`(...)`) in the regex matched; `break` stops processing instantly.

---

A *more concise, but slower* option is to combine the `-match` and [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operators, but note that this will only work as intended if only *one* line matches:

```
((Get-Content ./sample.txt) -match '^\s*key1=' -split '=')[1]
```

Also note that this invariably involves reading the *entire file*, by loading *all* lines into an array up front via [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content).

---

A comparatively *slow* version - due to using a *cmdlet* and thereby implicitly the *pipeline* - that fixes your attempt:

```
(Select-String -List '^\s*key1=(.*)' ./sample.txt).Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
```

Note:

- [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) outputs *wrapper objects* of type [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) that wrap metadata around the matching strings rather than returning them directly (the way that `grep` does); `.Matches` is the property that contains the details of the match, which allows accessing what the capture group (`(...)`) in the regex captured, but it's not exactly obvious how to access that information.
- The `-List` switch ensures that processing stops at the *first* match, but note that this only works with a *direct file argument* rather than with piping a file's lines individually via `Get-Content`.
- Note that `-AllMatches` is for finding multiple matches *in a single line* (input object), and therefore not necessary here.

---

Another *slow* solution that uses [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) with a script block in which each line is [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) into the key and value part, as suggested by [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert):

```
Get-Content ./sample.txt | ForEach-Object { 
  $key, $val = $_ -split '='
  if ($key -eq 'key1') { $val } 
}
```

**Caveat**: This invariably processes *all* lines, even after the key of interest was found.

- To prevent that, you can append `| Select-Object -First 1` to the command.
- Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.1 there is *no* way to directly exit a pipeline on demand from a script block; see long-standing [GitHub feature request #3821](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821).

  - Note that `break` does *not* work as intended - except if you wrap your pipeline in a *dummy loop* statement (such as `do { ... } while ($false)`) to break out of.